# Jquery: window.unload not working with chrome 72.0.3626.109

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a web app using `asp.net mvc`. I want to detect a manual refresh by a user,

but I am not able to get the following events

> 1: beforeunload
>
> 2: unload

the following way I Tried

> 1

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    pageCleanup();
});
```

> 2

```
$(window).on("unload", function () {
    pageCleanup();
});

function pageCleanup() {  
    alert(1)
}
```

> 3

```
window.addEventListener("unload", logData);

function logData() {
    alert(1)
}
```

> 4

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    alert('1');
});
```

> the above is an example with alert, I want to have an ajax call in
>   unload function

but none of these seems to execute when a user press any kind of refresh(F5, ctrl-shift-R, ctrl-R, from url tab)

what should I try now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Check Once and Let me know

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Refresh a page in jQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Stop a page from exit with jQuery</h1>

<button id="reload">Refresh a Page in jQuery</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#reload').click(function() {

        location.reload();

    });

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n bro!!Working';
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `bind` for `beforeunload`:

```js
$(window).bind("beforeunload", () => alert(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```