# Why browser refresh and close event detection is not working for IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-close

I need to call `logout function` on the close of browser window gets close. It's working fine in Chrome not working in IE and Safari.

I have tried the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    // Your logic to prepare for 'Stay on this Page' goes here
    var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
    if (evtobj == e) {
        //firefox
        if (!evtobj.clientY) {
           //server call
        }
    }
    else {
        //IE
        if (evtobj.clientY < 0) {
           //server call
        }
    }
    //return "Please click 'Stay on this Page' and we will give you candy";
};
```

I have tried a few other ways but they didn't work. Please advise.

Comment: Hi can you check this link might it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801161/7924858  please up-vote

Comment: Thanks @abhinavxeon, Already tried, not working.

Comment: There are many ways a browser window can be closed so a pure detection of the window getting close would be, unfortunately (sort of, fortunately) impossible. JavaScript has onundload and onbeforeunload events but they can-not cross the boundaries that the security restricitions has set for them.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in your design, you SHOULDN'T rely on a client-side hook to perform logout. There are one billion of reasons why that event could not be executed. Just limit the `onbeforeunload` event to execute informational content and not critical actions.

By the way:

- Don't return in your `beforeunload` event! This creates some issue in IE
- Use `window.sessionStorage` to make some data last until the user closes the tab
- Use session cookies to store your user's sensitive data like as tokens, and check if a user is logged on the server, and not on the client

Comment: Thanks @Cristian Traìna, I tried browser session storage, but session storage will clear once you close the browser. So I am not able to validate whether it's refresh or close on  this.